# webapp2 - how do I include library

Tags: python-2.7, webapp2

I am testing Google Cloud and first I wanted to develop something on my PC before I use in on google cloud.
I am using APACHE and configured it in that way, that when I am going to the page localhost/wsgi_app I see my page which physically is stored in folder /svc/http/webapp2. File wsgi_app.py which contains my app is stored in subfolder webapp2. All works fine. I provide this information just in case it might play any role.

The issue I have is with import from library.
I did it on Django and now try to move it to webapp2.

The first lines of my program look like this:

```
import webapp2
import MySQLdb
import json
```

I have file called test.py which contains some classess and funtions.
it is in the same folder as wsgi_app.py.
I want to include it, however this seems not to work:

```
import webapp2
import MySQLdb
import json
from test import *
```

my test.py contains definition of the class 'Quote', but when I call the page I see error

```
NameError: global name 'Quote' is not defined
```

When I put the inside of the file test.py in the file wsgi_app.py all works fine.
My goal is to separate the code into several files.

Any idea why :

```
from test import *
```

does not work ?
It worked on any other program I wrote, so why not here?

Answer (score 0):

issue solved.

issue is not related to weapp2 but to WSGI and the path where python search for files.
Most simple solution is to add something like this ;
execfile("/srv/http/test.py")
it will import the file.

other than this here is quite good article
http://blog.dscpl.com.au/2014/09/python-module-search-path-and-modwsgi.html